# Meteor and mongodg exit code 1 on debian wheezy

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

i just finished installing my all-new debian wheezy distribution. I would like to install the meteor framework, so I did:

```
sudo curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

as recommended by the official [meteor website](https://www.meteor.com/), but during the installation I get this error when I type `meteor` after creating a new meteor project:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.     
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.     
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.     
Can't start Mongo server.                     
MongoDB failed global initialization

Looks like MongoDB doesn't understand your locale settings. See
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4019 for more details
```

In fact, once a new project is created and operational after coding, the `meteor` command run a localhost web server on port 3000 and then we can see the web application.

I don't understand why I get this error. Is it possible that my problems are coming from my debian distribution?

Comment: Oops, seems my firts words are missing... it was "hello everyone"

Comment: one more thong, i already see the link at the end and the problem solved itself but it doesn't work for me after a few hours unfortunately...

Comment: thanks to peak for editing my post. I tried to reinstall debian but no effect the problem still here.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Let us know if you solve the issue!

Comment: Yes i did, sorry for keep you waiting. The probleme was solved by changing locale. "locale-gen en_US.UTF8
localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-"

Answer (score 1):

Do: `$: LC_ALL=<your language>`
where  is the system language. Like `de_DE.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

in console:

```
export PORT=3000
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor
export ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
export HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT=1
```